# Is there a way to filter using count of a nested array item when using OData Query?

Tags: odata, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using Microsoft Graph [List CalendarView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) to get calendar events from outlook. I would like to filter out items where count of attendees is 0. (Logically meaning time blocked for self).

I understand there is a $count parameter that will return the count of items. However, in the List CalendarView response i am not after the count of calendar items, but rather the count of attendees within each calendar item.  And infact to use a *not equal (ne)* filter based on it.

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "originalStartTimeZone": "originalStartTimeZone-value",
      "originalEndTimeZone": "originalEndTimeZone-value",
      "iCalUId": "iCalUId-value",
      "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 99,
      "isReminderOn": true,
      "attendees":[
            {
                "type":"required",
                "status":{
                    "response":"none",
                    "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress":{
                    "name":"Samantha Booth",
                    "address":"samanthab@a830edad905084922E17020313.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type":"required",
                "status":{
                    "response":"none",
                    "time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
                },
                "emailAddress":{
                    "name":"Dana Swope",
                    "address":"danas@a830edad905084922E17020313.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to specifically filter out any event items where the array size of "attendees" is 0.

Is this feasible using OData query params?

Answer (score 1):

It appears filtering against `attendees` property is not supported, see for example, [this thread](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1771) for a details. But the following approach could be considered:

a) introduce an [extended property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/extended-properties-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) for [`event` resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0) which will expose summary info (flag whether event contains attendees or the *count of attendees*) about `attendees`.

Update all the existing events:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event-id}
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
      {
         "id":"String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00047ec6ac6e} Name ContainsAttendes",
         "value":"1"
      }
    ]
}
```

b) now events could be filtered like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00047ec6ac6e} Name ContainsAttendes' and ep/value eq '1')
```

where it is assumed `ContainsAttendes=1` corresponds to events which have one or more attendees